# Custom jQuery Form Validation - What Is The Best Way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to create a custom jQuery form validation script to help me learn jQuery and it's best practices better. But the minute I started, I found myself with more questions than solutions. I know there is the jQuery validation plugin, and a bunch of other third party plugins but this is something I wanted to create from scratch.

My first attempt yield something like this below. It works great, but just seems like a lot of code to validate basically the same type of input filed all the way down the form.

```
$(".validation").submit(function(){
  if($(".name").val() === ""){
    $(".name").addClass("error");
    $(".errorMessage").html("<p>Error: Please enter a valid name</p>").slideDown();
    return false;
  }if($(".address1").val() === ""){
    $(".address1").addClass("error");
    $(".errorMessage").html("<p>Error: Please enter a valid address</p>").slideDown();
    return false;
  }if($(".city").val() === ""){
    $(".city").addClass("error");
    $(".errorMessage").html("<p>Error: Please enter a valid city</p>").slideDown();
    return false;
  }if($(".state").val() === "0"){
    $(".state").addClass("error");
    $(".errorMessage").html("<p>Error: Please enter a valid state</p>").slideDown();
    return false;
  }if($(".zipCode").val() === ""){
    $(".zipCode").addClass("error");
    $(".errorMessage").html("<p>Error: Please enter a valid zip code</p>").slideDown();
    return false;
  }if($(".phone").val() === ""){
    $(".phone").addClass("error");
    $(".errorMessage").html("<p>Error: Please enter a valid phone</p>").slideDown();
    return false;
  }if($(".email").val() === "" || ! /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/.test($(".email").val())){
    $(".email").addClass("error");
    $(".errorMessage").html("<p>Error: Please enter a valid email</p>").slideDown();
    return false;
  }
});
```

My second attempt yielded something like this below. This cut down on all the if statements but with event bubbling, it is validating the form backwards. It also only adds one error message with at a time with `$(".errorMessage").html("There was an error" + " " + name);`. Would it be possible to show this error message for every empty form field at the same time rather than one at a time? I have a [CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/jbatzel1Development/pen/LIncs) of this working.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
  $("input").each(function(){

    var name = $(this).attr("name");

    if($(this).val() == ""){
      $(".errorMessage").html("There was an error" + " " + name);
      e.preventDefault();
    }else{
      return true; 
    }
  });
});
```

Any suggestions on technique or best practices would be great.

Thanks,

JB

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Just out of curiosity what is the point of the extra " " in the error? Just append the space in the first part...

Comment: Rick, Thanks for the comment. I like the idea of using append and I know in this example it's irrelevant but for performance purposes wouldn't just adding it like I have improve performance theoretically?

Comment: Please do not tag the question with a plugin you're not using.  Tag-spam removed.

Comment: Rick, Never mind I see where you are coming from! Thanks

Comment: Sparky, Sorry about that. Was not intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. If you want to do that, you will need to decide how exactly you want to show those errors. Some people will put each error into a list item with some kind of heading before the list, such as "Please correct the following errors:". Then you would create an li element, set it's text to the error, and append it to your ul list object.

You could also do some type of sentence creation to make a plain English sentence that tells the user what is wrong, but I typically prefer the list option. Honestly, there are an infinite number of ways of doing this.

Hopefully I understood your question thoroughly though, let me know if not.

Edit: Here's a quick and dirty example, taken from your example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hJdtD

Comment: Bit Destroyer, Thanks, this was very helpful!

Comment: Bit Destroyer, I worked off of the code you supplied which really helped expand my scope on how jQuery can work. How does this code look to you below? Could it be used as production code and/or are the concepts right? `$("form").on("submit", function(e){
  $("input").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ""){
      
      var name = $(this).attr("name");
      var li= $("<li></li>", {
        text: "There was an error with " + name,
        class: "errorText",
       });
        
      $(".errorMessage").append(li);
      e.preventDefault();
    }else{
      return true; 
    }
  });
});`

Answer (score 0):

**General Concept Example.**

```
 Adds a validation method that checks if a given value equals the addition of the two parameters.

jQuery.validator.addMethod("math", function(value, element, params) { 
 return this.optional(element) || value == params[0] + params[1]; 
 }, jQuery.format("Please enter the correct value for {0} + {1}"));
```

**Custom Method Example:**

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThanZero", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || (parseFloat(value) > 0);
}, "* Amount must be greater than 0");

$('validatorElement').validate({
rules : {
    amount : { greaterThanZero : true }
}
});
```

Source
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod

Comment: Garry, Thanks for the quick response! I am a little confused by your example, but don't feel bad, I'm still new. I will look into the documentation that you linked to and see if I can figure it out!

Comment: as you are new to jquery it might take little time but you can easily do it...Good Luck...